# Clone/duplicate EE4/EE5 entries

Tags: ee4

I am looking for a way to clone channel entries with EE4/5.

There are posts mentioning MX Cloner and some others but they're very old and for EE2 only I think.

How could I go about it? Would it matter if the entries contain liquid fields?

**Is there a way to clone EE4/5 entries?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is also no.  Whether anyone will come up with an add-on to do this I'm not sure, but without such your options are really limited: especially when you factor in things like fluid, grid or relationship fields the duplication process becomes really complicated.  For some very simple cases you can duplicate fields by direct manipulation of the MySQL database entries, but in most real-world situations it is simply not practical.  EE's way of storing data within its database has changed significantly since EE2 days, and I imagine there is no easy way to update MX Cloner - so your best bet probably is to open two browser windows side by side and cut / paste content and copy field definitions across that way.